# How to define get and set methods

Tags: c#, class, methods, get, set

Thanks so much, your help is really appreciated. Its made realise how much I have to learn. Its the direction that I want to set and get to have adapted your examples to reflect this. However, its now asking for ; at the end of my static void Main.... even though I have never added this before, its asking to declare the body extern, abstract. Its also not letting me set the links whilst in Main, I am using the following syntax gh.setName("Great Hall"); gh.setN(dr); in order to set the north link between the great hall and the drawing room. Any idea?

```
private string RoomName;
        private Room N = null;
        private Room E = null;
        private Room S = null;
        private Room W = null;

        public Room X { get; private set; }

        public void setName(string N)
        {
            RoomName = N;
        }

        public void setN(Room X)
        {
            N = X;
        }

        public void setE(Room X)
        {
            E = X;
        }

        public void setW(Room X)
        {
            W = X;
        }

        public void setS(Room x)
        {
            S = X;
        }


        public Room getN()
        {
            return N;
        }

        public Room getE()
        {
            return E;
        }

        public Room getS()
        {
            return S;
        }

        public Room getW()
        {
            return W;
        }




        static void Main(string[] args)

      Room gh = new Room();
        Room kit = new Room();
        Room Pan = new Room();
        Room Dun = new Room();
        Room dr = new Room();
        Room lib = new Room();
        Room din = new Room();
        Room sr = new Room();
        Room weap = new Room();
        Room tow = new Room();
        Room gal = new Room();
        Room tr = new Room();

        gh.setName("Great Hall");
            gh.setN(dr);
```

Comment: The reason your `setN` method isn't compiling is that you've got a rogue `;` at the end of the declaration. But as per answers, you should learn about properties.

Comment: Yes, it's the `;`. The reason for your error message is that with the semicolon at the end of `setN` you finish your method declaration without a body (that is the part enclosed by `{}`). That is only allowed for `extern`, `abstract` and`partial` methods.

Comment: The Main method is also a method, so you need to embrace the code inside into `{` and `}`

Comment: I realise that I need to embrace the code but in debugging it keeps adding a ; to the end of static void Main(string[] args) and states that a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle properties explicitly like this:

```
private string _roomName;

public string roomName {
   get {
       return _roomName;
   }
   set {
      _roomName = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `C#` you can use simple way of dealing with properties:

```
public string RoomName {get; set;}
```

Will create a default property with `GET` and `SET`. It will also create a field for you, that you don't have to bother about that.

If you need to do something more you can use fields:

```
private string _roomName;

public string RoomName {
   get {
       //do something before returning
       return _roomName;
   }
   set {
      //do something while value is being set
      _roomName = value;
   }
}
```

If you are using new C# (6.0) you can use that syntax as well:

```
private string _roomName;
public string RoomName => _roomName;
```

When you are building property in code, that what's probably happens underneath:
Compiler translates property into set of two methods looks like that:

```
public string Get_RoomName() {
    return _roomName;
}

public void Set_RoomName(string value) {
    _roomName = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, according to your error:

> SetN must declare a body as extern, abstract or partial and this comes up for my both get and set methods.

Please close the `}` at the end of your `class Room`!

and remove the `;` after `public void setN(Room X);`!

In C# you can use [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx) to get the functionality of get and set methods:

this is a short Variant:

```
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

and this is the explicit version:

```
private Room myN;

public Room N
{
    get { return myN; }
    set { myN = value; }
}
```

In the extended Version you have a private field, which is inaccessible from outside, and you have a public property. It has a `set { myVar = value; }`
 section which is the equivalent to your set-method.

EDIT: as suggested by@Jens:  `value` is a default parameter that contains the value being passed from the outside to the set method. It is always called `value` and not expliictly declared in C#

Calling convention when setting would be to use it like a class variable:

```
Room AnyRoom = new Room();
Room X = new Room();
AnyRoom.N = X;
```

Comment: You're all forgetting he declared it as `private`.

Comment: Maybe to make it even clearer, you could mention that `value` is a default parameter that contains the value being passed from the outside to the `set` method. It is always called `value` and not explictly declared in C#.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne is looks like a Java-approach. Having a private field and public get- and set-methods. Why bothering to write a get-method if you don't want this private field to be accessed